# KrakenJS and Adaro or Engine-Munger or Dust... (grunt build and then npm start)

Tags: javascript, node.js, kraken.js

So I'm trying to put my server on a production environment. I'm using kraken, and almost the same config at init. At development all works fine but then I do (I am on Windows 8.1 64bits):

```
set NODE_ENV=production
grunt build --force
npm start
```

For root files it works fine, the problem is for folders. I take this at command line:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2014:05:55:41 +0000] "GET /back/login HTTP/1.1" 500 22 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36" Error: Could
>   not load template
>       at Object.onLoad (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\engine-munger\view\js.js:38:22)
>       at Object.cache.get (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\engine-munger\lib\cache.js:59:14)
>       at spclOnLoad (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\engine-munger\lib\munger.js:75:9)
>       at C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\adaro\lib\reader\file.js:62:16
>       at onChunk (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\adaro\lib\patch\index.js:69:29)
>       at Chunk.map (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\dustjs-linkedin\lib\dust.js:587:7)
>       at C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\adaro\lib\patch\index.js:91:39
>       at Object.dust.load [as __cabbage__] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\dustjs-linkedin\lib\dust.js:137:14)
>       at Object.cabbage [as load] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\adaro\lib\patch\index.js:98:21)
>       at Object.dust.render (C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\node_modules\dustjs-linkedin\lib\dust.js:92:12)

It seems to not find the appropriate path or something like that.
Also at config I have:
http://pastebin.com/QsgG19Uz

I have posted in pastebin because its large. Any Idea how to make this work? Can `NODE_ENV=development` make troubles on a production server?

EDIT:

Here is the final output on "grunt build --force":

> > > 432 errors in 43 files Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Used --force, continuing. Running "clean:tmp" (clean) task Cleaning tmp...OK
>
> Running "copyto:build" (copyto) task Copied 36 files (0 unchanged),
>   created 4 folders
>
> Done, but with warnings.

The thing is, I have tried the same with the Shopping Cart Example at Krakenjs website, and it gives mostly the same.

Also, It says warnings, not errors at final...

Comment: Yes, `development` environment can make trouble on a production server: It doesn't use precompiled templates, and performance can be quite poor. You can compare the configurations by looking at the configuration in the kraken-js config directory.

Comment: Why the `--force` to `grunt`? It makes me suspect that templates aren't being built and you're ignoring the error. What's the output of grunt?

Comment: Hi @Aredridel I have added what I get (Exluding files) when I execute "grunt build --force" At ".build" is created a folder with another folder called "templates" and then inside "US/en" there is the same I have at "public/templates" but instead of html is js, and inside is a one line (large line) of javascript with dust. For example: '(function(){dust.register("terms",body_0);var bloc..."

Comment: That doesn't look like complete output -- there are errors mentioned but not in what you pasted.

Comment: And `.build/templates` should indeed contain javascript -- those are the compiled dust templates, ready to execute.

Comment: You never answered: why `--force`

Comment: Hi @Aredridel, sorry I has been busy :S. So I have been working on my code, and I now have JShint without problems (But some tweaks on the config which I will recover sometime in the near future), but before fix that, I found this Error: `>> SyntaxError: Expected buffer, comment, end of input, partial, raw, reference,
 section or special but "{" found. At line : 88, column : 1` The only way I have found to get not showing the error at the console is to delete almost all the html code at the dust file. Its a children template, but I can't get it working...

Comment: Also the --force I was using it because I thougth it was problem of Jshint and I read is "just" a convention check tool so I disabled (I thought is was what it was doing) to check if the code then works. But no... It just some error I can't find in my templates code... also that error I cant find it on Google, I mean, yes, I found it, but is not a clear answer for my situation, I think... Thanks for all!

Comment: Ah, so the problem is in compiling dust template -- a syntax error doing that. Can you show the dust template that causes the problem?

Comment: @Aredridel Hi, so here is the layout code and the child code, I have modified a little bit to hide some stuff but keeps crashing with the same error. Layout: http://pastebin.com/U4EKPgCe and the child http://pastebin.com/AsKRTVxF It's in spanish, the thing is... before it gives this error, it compiles without problems other templates with the same layout... I don't have any idea where can be the problem :( Thanks!

Comment: Also, maybe some files compiles whitout problems but then when I try to enter at production mode It fails... But the main page is working... is like the problem is in the folders... site.com works but site.com/back/login doesnt... it's weird...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is just fun: I bet embedded CSS and Javascript are setting off a compile error in dust. There's a lot of things in curly braces that look like dust tags there. It should be smart enough to tell the difference -- and for JS, probably is -- but CSS is pretty close to dust and I'm sure there's some ambiguity there.

Try externalizing your JS and CSS from the layout and see if that helps.